# Could not cast value of type (0x10ca9be10) to 'NSString' (0x7fff86d8bbb0)

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, tableview

Hello good afternoon to everyone.
I hope you are doing very well despite the situation we are going through.

I tell you my problem.
I am trying to save in an array, a series of data that is selected from a tableView through a JSON.
That is, the tableView shows some data available to select, the ones that are selected I want to save them in an array but when I select a data in the tableView my app crashes and shows me a breakpoint "**Thread 1: signal SIGABRT**"

And in the console I get this:
**Could not cast value of type 'MallConcierge.DetallesIntereses' (0x10ca9be10) to 'NSString' (0x7fff86d8bbb0).**

I hope you can help me, I attach the classes from where I download the data, the details and the class where I connect the tableView.

**InteresesModelo.swift** (in this class is where I download the data in JSON)

```
import UIKit

protocol InteresesModeloProtocol: class{
    func interesesDownload (interest: NSArray)
}

class InteresesModelo: NSObject {
    
    weak var delegate: InteresesModeloProtocol!
    
    let urlPath = "http://localhost:8888/mallconcierge/API-movil/interests.php"
    
    func interestDownload(){
        
        let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
        let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral)
        URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url){
            (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil{
                
                print("Error al descargar datos")
                
            }else{
                
                print("Datos descargados")
                self.parseJSON(data!)
                
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        
    }
    
    func parseJSON(_ data:Data){
        
        var jsonResult = NSArray()
        do{
            jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray
        }catch let error as NSError{
            print(error)
        }
        var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
        let detalles = NSMutableArray()
        
        for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count{
            
            jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary
            let detalle = DetallesIntereses()
            
            let idInteres = jsonElement["idInteres"]
            let nombreInteres = jsonElement["interesNombre"]
            
            detalle.idInteres = idInteres as? String
            detalle.nombreInteres = nombreInteres as? String
            
            detalles.add(detalle)
            
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { ()-> Void in
            
            self.delegate.interesesDownload(interest: detalles)
        })
            
        
    }

}
```

**DetallesIntereses.swift**

```
import UIKit

class DetallesIntereses: NSObject {
    
    var idInteres: String?
    var nombreInteres: String?
    
    override init() {
        
    }
    
    init(idInteres: String, nombreInteres:String) {
        
        self.idInteres = idInteres
        self.nombreInteres = nombreInteres
        
    }
    
    override var description: String{
        
        return "idInteres: \(idInteres), nombreInteres: \(nombreInteres)"
        
    }

}
```

InteresesViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class InteresesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,   InteresesModeloProtocol {
    
    var selectIntereses = [String]()
    
    var feedInterests: NSArray = NSArray()
    
   // var selectInterests: DetallesIntereses = DetallesIntereses()
    
    var items=[String]()
    
    @IBOutlet var listaInteresesTableView: UITableView!

    func interesesDownload(interest: NSArray) {
        
        feedInterests = interest
        self.listaInteresesTableView.reloadData()
        
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        self.listaInteresesTableView.isEditing = true
        self.listaInteresesTableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true

        self.listaInteresesTableView.delegate = self
        self.listaInteresesTableView.dataSource = self
        
        let interesesModelo = InteresesModelo()
        interesesModelo.delegate = self
        interesesModelo.interestDownload()
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return feedInterests.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "celInterests", for: indexPath) as! InteresesTableViewCell
        
        let interest: DetallesIntereses = feedInterests[indexPath.row] as! DetallesIntereses
        
        cell.lblNombreIntereses!.text = interest.nombreInteres
        
        return cell
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        

        
        self.selectDeselectCell(tableView: listaInteresesTableView, indexPath: indexPath)
        print("Seleccionado")
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.selectDeselectCell(tableView: listaInteresesTableView, indexPath: indexPath)
        print("Deseleccionado")
    }
    
    func selectDeselectCell(tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath){
        self.selectIntereses.removeAll()
        
        if let arr = listaInteresesTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows{
     
            
            for index in arr{
                selectIntereses.append(feedInterests[indexPath.row] as! String)
            }
        }
        print(selectIntereses)
    }
    
    @IBAction func seleccionarIntereses(_ sender: Any){
        
        print(selectIntereses)

    }
    
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

The JSON

```
[
{
    "idInteres": "1",
    "interesNombre": "Moda Mujer"
},
{
    "idInteres": "3",
    "interesNombre": "Moda Hombre"
},
{
    "idInteres": "4",
    "interesNombre": "Belleza"
},
{
    "idInteres": "5",
    "interesNombre": "Relojes y Joyería"
},
{
    "idInteres": "6",
    "interesNombre": "Hogar/Interiorismo"
},
{
    "idInteres": "7",
    "interesNombre": "Gastronomía"
},
{
    "idInteres": "8",
    "interesNombre": "Entretenimiento"
},
{
    "idInteres": "9",
    "interesNombre": "Wellness"
}
```

]

I hope you can help me, please.
I thank you all

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of little stuff going on here. I've tried to highlight as I make edits with `//<-- Here`.

By far the biggest issue is using the untyped Objective-C `NSArray` instead of using a typed Swift array. By switching to that, you can get useful type errors.

I had to make a couple of assumptions about what you wanted to do, but this should get you started.

I've left the original JSON decoding for the most part, but I'd *strongly* suggest you look into using `Codable` instead of `JSONSerialization` unless you have a compelling reason not to.

```
protocol InteresesModeloProtocol : AnyObject {
    func interesesDownload (interest: [DetallesIntereses]) //<-- Here
}

class InteresesModelo: NSObject {
    
    weak var delegate: InteresesModeloProtocol!
    
    let urlPath = "http://localhost:8888/mallconcierge/API-movil/interests.php"
    
    func interestDownload(){
        
        let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
        let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral)
        URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url){
            (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil{
                
                print("Error al descargar datos")
                
            }else{
                
                print("Datos descargados")
                self.parseJSON(data!)
                
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        
    }
    
    func parseJSON(_ data:Data){
        
        var jsonResult = [[String:String]]()
        do{
            jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [[String : String]]
        }catch let error as NSError{
            print(error)
        }
        
        let detalles = jsonResult.map { jsonElement -> DetallesIntereses in
            let detalle = DetallesIntereses(idInteres: jsonElement["idInteres"], nombreInteres: jsonElement["interesNombre"])
            return detalle
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.delegate.interesesDownload(interest: detalles)
        }
            
        
    }

}


struct DetallesIntereses { //<-- Here -- no reason for this to be an `NSObject`
    var idInteres: String?
    var nombreInteres: String?
}


class InteresesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,   InteresesModeloProtocol {
    
    var selectIntereses = [DetallesIntereses]()   //<-- Here
    
    var feedInterests: [DetallesIntereses] = []  //<-- Here
    
    var items = [String]()
    
    @IBOutlet var listaInteresesTableView: UITableView!

    func interesesDownload(interest: [DetallesIntereses]) { //<-- Here
        feedInterests = interest  //<-- Here
        self.listaInteresesTableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        self.listaInteresesTableView.isEditing = true
        self.listaInteresesTableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true

        self.listaInteresesTableView.delegate = self
        self.listaInteresesTableView.dataSource = self
        
        let interesesModelo = InteresesModelo()
        interesesModelo.delegate = self
        interesesModelo.interestDownload()
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return feedInterests.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "celInterests", for: indexPath) as! InteresesTableViewCell
        
        let interest: DetallesIntereses = feedInterests[indexPath.row]  //<-- Here
        
        cell.lblNombreIntereses!.text = interest.nombreInteres
        
        return cell
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.selectDeselectCell(tableView: listaInteresesTableView, indexPath: indexPath)
        print("Seleccionado")
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.selectDeselectCell(tableView: listaInteresesTableView, indexPath: indexPath)
        print("Deseleccionado")
    }
    
    func selectDeselectCell(tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath){
        self.selectIntereses.removeAll()
        
        selectIntereses.append(feedInterests[indexPath.row]) //<-- Here
        print(selectIntereses)
    }
    
    @IBAction func seleccionarIntereses(_ sender: Any){
        
        print(selectIntereses)

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi how are you?
Thank you very much for the help.

I honestly do not have much knowledge in Swift because I do not program in this language regularly.
Downloading and displaying data in the table is not the problem, as the data was already displayed.
From that data that is shown to the table, the user must select the data, whatever it is, and the selected data must be stored in an array.
With the code that you share with me, the application only saves a single data in the array and the intention is that only the "jsonElement [" interesNombre "]" string are saved in the array.

Thanks!

Comment: Okay -- do you know how to edit the code that I gave you to make it store only `interesNombre` or are you asking me to edit the answer?

Comment: No, I don't really know how to edit it because I don't have much knowledge of swift, but I will try. The code that you share works but it only saves a single data in the array.
Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really following your comments here. I'm happy to try to edit, but I'm not sure what "saves a single data in the array" means. In what array?